# How do disconnect tippy popup from clicked element

Tags: tippyjs

I'm battling Tippy popup placement problems where a portion of the popup appears outside of the viewport.  I cannot make this appear in the viewport for all clicked locations (and the popped up  does fit easily).  For the elements at the top, the popup appears below the element - ok.  For the elements at the bottom, the popup appears above the element - also ok.  For a bunch in middle, the popup appears truncated either above or below) - it seems like tippy cant figure out how to keep the popup inside the viewport in this scenario.

I read somewhere that I can disconnect the popup location from the clicked element but cannot find any docs on how to do that (latest Tippy 6.x lib).

So how can I make the tippy popup appear in the middle of the viewport? (this is an acceptable workaround if we cant get the auto-placement to work within the boundaries of the viewport)